# Getting ND behaviour of `np.dot` with `np.tensortdot` or 2-D only `np.dot`

Tags: numpy, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to express the N-D behaviour of `np.dot` using *only* 2-D `np.dot` or `np.tensordot`.

To recap, `np.dot` does something like the following for N-D: It matches/broadcasts the arrays along all dimensions but the last two and performs dot products for all of them. For example, if `x.shape` is `(2, 3, 4, 5)` and `y.shape` is `(2, 3, 5, 4)`, `np.dot(x, y).shape` is `(2, 3, 4, 4)` and `np.dot(x, y)[i, j]` is `np.dot(x[i, j], y[i, j])`.

Also, if `x.shape` is just `(4, 5)`, it will first be converted to `(2, 3, 5, 4)` via `np.broadcast`.

I tried `np.tensortdot(x, y, axes=(-1, -2))` but it repeats along every dimension of `x`, `y` instead of matching them up.

I realise I could write a loop but I was looking for a vectorised solution.

Comment: Think you should be using `matmul` : `np.matmul(a,b)` or `a @ b`.

Comment: @Divakar That works, but I acually want to do this with `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.dot`, which only has 2D

Comment: Sparse matrices are 2d, period.  It's not just their `dot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the broadcasting behavior of `np.dot` wrong:

```
In [254]: x=np.ones((2,3,4,5)); y=np.ones((2,3,5,4))
In [255]: np.dot(x,y).shape
Out[255]: (2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4)
In [256]: np.matmul(x,y).shape
Out[256]: (2, 3, 4, 4)
```

and for the (4,5) `x`:

```
In [257]: np.dot(x[0,0],y).shape
Out[257]: (4, 2, 3, 4)
In [258]: np.matmul(x[0,0],y).shape
Out[258]: (2, 3, 4, 4)
```

`matmul` was added precisely because `np.dot` does not act like it is performing `np.dot(x[i,j,:,:], y[i,j,:,:])` for all `i,j`.

The shape in `Out[255]` is the shape of `x` minus the 5, plus the shape of `y` minus its 5.  In effect an outer produce of everything with summing on the size 5 dimension.

`tensordot` uses `np.dot`.  It just reshapes and transposes the inputs to reduce the problem to a 2d `dot` one.  Then it massages the result back to the desired shape and order.

```
In [259]: np.tensordot(x, y, axes=(-1,-2)).shape
Out[259]: (2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4)   # cf Out[255]

In [261]: np.einsum('ijkl,ijlm->ijkm',x,y).shape
Out[261]: (2, 3, 4, 4)    # cf Out[256]
```

---

Since sparse matrices are 2d to start with - and end with, I don't understand your question.  If you have multiple sparse matrices, you'll have to work with them individually.